# Xpath for //a class

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath

I am trying to find xpath for Template 1.  So far I have tried following but nothing works.  I am trying to get Template 1

```
    //a[@class='treenode' and contains(text(),'Template 1')]

//div[@id='objTree~templates~750764_children' and text()='Template 1']


//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:void(0)')]/text()
//a[contains(text(), 'Template 1')]

//a[@class='treenode' and starts-with(@href, '/javascript/')]

//a[text()="Template 1"]

//a[normalize-space(.) = 'Template 1']
```

Here is my HTML

```
<a class="treenode" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="; highlightNode(this);" oncontextmenu="return showContext(this);">Template 1</a>
```

`Ruby` code:

```
link(:my_template1, :xpath=> "//a[@class='treenode' and contains(text(),'Template 1')]")
```

what is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: What tool do you use? Is it `Selenium`?

Comment: Yes , it is Ruby selenium

Comment: Share your `ruby` code also

Comment: link(:my_template1, :xpath=> "//a[@class='treenode' and contains(text(),'Template 1')]")

Comment: @arm If you are ready to use Selenium Ruby Binding, Use WATIR, it's a nice wrapper around Ruby selenium binding, The time issue you have would never arises because they have handled it very nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expressions seem to be OK, but the link might be generated dynamically by some JavaScript, so you get `NoSuchElementException` as it's not present in the initial DOM. You can try to wait until link appears in the DOM.

I'm not sure about the Ruby syntax. Try this and let me know if it doesn't work:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:link_text  => "Template 1") }
element.click
```

Comment: what is :link_text? is it xpath?

Comment: No. It is search by visible link text. But if you want to use `XPath` you can replace `:link_text  => "Template 1"` with `:xpath  => "//a[text()='Template 1']"`. These locators actually means the same